# Windows 10 Spelling Autocorrect not working

Tags: windows-10, spell-check

I'm on a Windows 10 Pro x64 desktop and the following setting to enable spellcheck doesn't seem to be working:

> Settings > Devices > Typing > Spelling > Autocorrect misspelled words

I've enabled it but it seems to have no effect whatsoever when I type incorrect words, it doesn't highlight or provide corrections:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What make you think Notepad supports this feature?

Answer (score 1):

#### It seems to have no effect whatsoever when I type incorrect words.

The most likely explanation is that Notepad doesn't use the Windows Spell Checking API.

> It works in some universal apps (especially built-in apps like Edge
>   and popular apps like Facebook), but not in others. It’s up to app
>   developers whether they want to use the Windows Spell Checking API or
>   not. **Autocorrect doesn’t work on most traditional desktop apps at
>   all**. It can even interfere with other spellchecker apps or services
>   you might have installed, such as Spell Check Anywhere or Grammarly.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [How to disable auto-correct and highlighted misspelled words in Windows 10 | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-spell-checker-windows-10)